# Jenkins and TestNG results encoding

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, jenkins, testng, jenkins-plugins

I am use Jenkins to build my Maven project and post testng results using plugin. Have a problem with cyrillic symbols in report. It's look like: ��������. But
cyrillic output in Jenkins console is OK.

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ru.ibs</groupId>
  <artifactId>msprjtest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.32.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
            <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources> 
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.googlecode</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
            <!--vmParameters>-Dfile.encofing=UTF-8</vmParameters-->
            <compileInBackground>false</compileInBackground>
    </configuration>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> 
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${basedir}/test-output</reportsDirectory>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven-idea-plugin-repo</id>
        <url>http://maven-idea-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/maven-repo</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <!-- profiles -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ie9</id>
            <properties>
                <env>local</env>
                <user.username></user.username>
                <user.password></user.password>
                <grid2.hub></grid2.hub>
                <site.url>http://msprjtest:6005/</site.url>
                <browser.name>ie</browser.name>
                <browser.version></browser.version>
                <browser.platform></browser.platform>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Project encoding is set to UTF-8. IDE is Intellij IDEA 12.1.3. TestNG 6.8.5.

Comment: Just to be precise, the encoding is bad in the report files (those under ./target/surefire-reports/) or in the test log (that is what you see when you run 'mvn test' in terminal)?

Comment: Bad encoding in ./target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml
Jenkins output console = encoding OK
In terminal and IDEA if i build project using "mvn test" encoding is bad too. If i run test from IDEA using testng.xml - encoding OK
In pom.xml i set UTF-8 for project.build.sourceEncoding and for maven-resources and compiler plugin. But it has no effect on output.

Comment: I tried to recreate some minimal setup and didn't reproduce the issue (ubuntu is my equipment so it's utf-8 all over). Still you might look into the compiled test classes to see if your Cyrillic messages are compiled correctly. If the class contains garbage, then it's compiler who's guilty, otherwise it's the runner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually,

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
    <configuration>
        ...
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <inputEncoding>UTF-8</inputEncoding>
        <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
        <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -ea
        -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Should fix it.

Comment: in my case just `<argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>` was enough