# Selenium Webdriver -TestNG: How to print Arabic text

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVLSJ.png)I am using Selenium webdriver- TestNG, the Arabic text are showing as special characters under the console and under the testNG report.

how we can resolve this issue

Comment: Do you really think you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi Grzegorz,

When I run an automation(using java) under eclipse on testNG framework I got special character for statement that has assertion for Arabic test.

Do you knwo how this issue can be resolved

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. What character? Where? What do you expect?

Comment: The Arabic text are showing as special characters UNDER THE TESTNG report, I expected that the Arabic text will show as Arabic text not as special characters 

Please see the attached snapshot, I hope that you have got it now.

Comment: From your snapshot, I can see that you've already customized the testNG report up to some extent. (e.g. report output name and location). You just need to ensure that your reporter output is set to UTF-8 encoding. If you're using maven, you can check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16695084/2285470

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem has been resolved by following the below:
Added JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable. Variable name: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS Variable value: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

Comment: I found this is the only option worked for getting unicode (special) characters displayed in testNG extent reports(html). A sample program with main method was displaying unicode characters properly, while same code as a @Test was not. Thanks