# Trying to import CSV containing Arabic characters to the website by Selenium - Java, but when the data upload to the website it shows like that (???)

Tags: java, csv, selenium-webdriver

Read the CSV file and how to format it,
I'm trying to use Selenium with Java, to upload this file to the search fields, but this test is to show how the website will read the CSV file

```
package utiliites;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CSV {
    
    // This method will read and return data from a CSV file
    public static List<String[]> get(String filename) {
        List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String testRow;
        try {
            // Open and read the file
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            // Read data as long as it's not empty
            // Parse the data by comma using .split() method
            // Place into a temporary array, then add to List 
            while ((testRow = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] line = testRow.split(",");
                data.add(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: File not found " + filename);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Could not read " + filename);
        }
        return data;
    }

}
```

Read the CSV and here where is it showing like this (???)

```
package Test;

import java.util.List;

public class DataReadrs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readCSV();
    }

    private static void readCSV() {
        String filename = "C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\Delegation(IdealLandData).csv"; 
        List<String[]>records = utiliites.CSV.get(filename);
        
        for (String[] record : records) {
            for (String field : record) {
                System.out.println((record[0]));
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question so everyone will be able to reproduce the issue. This include posting code as code (not as image), page url or source code and the CSV file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Webdriver -TestNG: How to print Arabic text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44095038/selenium-webdriver-testng-how-to-print-arabic-text)

Comment: I couldn't understand this solution

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gb9e3m98avk how to add the system variable. `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` will be your `Variable name` and `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` will be it's value.

Comment: I'm using Java, and this library for python, so I'm not able to use it

Comment: And I edit the issue to make it as code rather than images

Comment: 'I'm using Java, and this library for python, so I'm not able to use it' What library? All you need is to add the system variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`.

Comment: I added it in this way, but the Arabic char is still showing as (???)JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS will be your Variable name and -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

Comment: My mistake, didn't read the reference anwser properly. The variable has to be as User variable (not system varible).